# How does this behaviour get marked in the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store

It's my understanding that when somebody has an app in the Play Store, they can monitor the number of installs and uninstalls of their app.

A few days a go I flashed my phone from the L preview to the official L release, and it re-installed some of my apps, but not all of them, and I wondered how this is marked in the Play Store.

My thoughts on what could happens is, my phone periodically checks what's installed, it will notice the app has gone, and mark it down as uninstalled, or...

It only marks it as uninstalled when I manually uninstall an app, so it's still marked as being installed even though it isn't.

Does anybody know how it's handled?